# Spring issue with webjar integration

Tags: xml, spring, resources, webjars

I am trying to add bootstrap and jquery via the dependency webjars
I added the following lines in my JSP :

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And my spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml looks like:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd     
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.meltum.*" />

<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
  <property name="definitions">
    <list>
      <value>/WEB-INF/tiles-def.xml</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
</bean>
```

When I remove the mvc:resources line in my XML the page is working else i get a 404 page.
Does anyone have an idea for my problem ?

Comment: Are you using a Servlet 3 compatible container?

Comment: @JamesWard To be honnest I don't know what that means but maybe not

Comment: @JamesWard if you are speaking about the dependance javax servlet (I saw on google that it refer to that) i can show you the dependance I put on my project

Comment: Are you using Tomcat?  What version?

Comment: @JamesWard it's working now, I posted an answer. thank you ;) I am using Tomecat 8

Comment: Servlet 3 containers (e.g. Tomcat 8) expose WebJars by default.  There must have been some conflict with previous versions of Spring and this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the version from 3.1 to 4.0 in my spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml
and put the mvc:resources at the end and a mvc:annotation-driven after

my spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml look like that now :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd     
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.meltum" />

<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
  <property name="definitions">
    <list>
      <value>/WEB-INF/tiles-def.xml</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
```